# XHR cannot load <URL>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, cgi, cors

I'm trying to execute a cross-domain AJAX request using JQuery. The server is executing a CGI file scripted in Python. I've tried adding CORS support to the server but it doesn't appear to be working, saying:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<URL>.cgi. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin <Other-URL> is therefore not allowed access.`

The JQuery AJAX request is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://<URL>.cgi",
})
.done(function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
});
```

and the server script is:

```
import os
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import sys
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

Username = form.getvalue('username')
Email    = form.getvalue('email')
Password = form.getvalue('password')

print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")

print("<\h2>Welcome, your credentials are as follows Username: %s Email: %s Password: %s </h2>" % (Username, Email, Password))  
print ("""
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
""")

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxxxx', password='xxxxxxx', host='127.0.0.1', database='xxxxxxx')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `user_information` (`User_ID`, `Email`, `Username`, `Password`) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s)", (Email, Username, Password))
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM  `user_information` LIMIT 0 , 30")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))

print ("""
</body>
</html>
""")
```

Comment: "I've tried adding CORS support to the server" Where? I don't see anything like this in your code (but a lot of irrelevant MySQL code).

Comment: print ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")

Comment: Try two more headers: `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS` and `ccess-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token`.

Comment: I tried adding them using:

`print("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS") 
print("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token")`

Still doesn't work though

Comment: Can you try adding `$.support.cors = true;` in your javascript? Also, where is your CORS support code server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` at the top of your script instead of in the output.  This finally solved it for me and didn't interfere with the script execution.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

import os
import cgi
etc...
```

Of course, you will probably want to whitelist a specific set of domains, instead of allowing all with *.

Answer (score 0):

Your print commands are not creating a valid [HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#General_format).
Instead of placing just placing

```
print ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
```

there you need to create the required CR-LF line endings and the two consecutive CR-LF to end the header. Also beware the automatic linefeed of the print command. This should work:

```
print ("Content-Type: text/html\r\n"),
print ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n\r\n"),
```